# Could not find method abiFilters() for arguments [x86]

Tags: java, android

**build.gradle(Module):**

```
externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
                 abiFilters 'x86'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs/'] } }
```

Could not find method abiFilters() for arguments [x86] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.CmakeOptions.

How fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
android {
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                abiFilters "x86"
            }
        }
    }
}
```